# Android device not recognized by Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

Samsung Galaxy S4. USB debugging is enabled. I selected to always prompt for device. All drivers are up to date and installed. Device version is 4.2, min sdk version is 8 and target is 18. I have restarted eclipse, my computer, and my device. Still will not recognize my device. BTW using Windows 7. Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance.

SOLVED: Thank you for the suggestions everyone, plugged it in the next morning and it worked. Must have been a driver not installed, but I did unplug and plug in numerous times.

Comment: I have a S4 and this happens to me sometimes. I just unplug it make sure it's unlocked and plug it back in. It should say it's connected as a media device in the notification tray. Is your S4 recognizing it is plugged in?

Comment: I forgot to mention that, my computer does recognize the device as being plugged in.

Comment: Have you installed Samsung's driver? Whether Samsung's software Kies can recognize your device?

Comment: The device says it is connected as a media device and Kies can recognize it

Answer (score 1):

Restarting the adb server, Eclipse, and device did the trick for me.

```
C:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>adb kill-server

C:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>adb start-server
```

- daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
- daemon started successfully *

Answer (score 1):

If your android device is not showing up at all then either

1. USB debugging is not enabled on your device OR
2. Suitable driver is not installed for the same.

You can check this case by running the command ./adb devices in the adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk\platform-tools directory. I have added the detailed solution for this my personal blog post - [Troubleshooting steps when Eclipse ADT does not recognizing your Android device](http://opensourceforgeeks.blogspot.in/2013/10/troubleshooting-steps-when-eclipse-adt.html).

If your android device is detected but is not recognized as in you are seeing something like `???? with no permissions` then you may want to restart your server. This is again explained with screenshots in my article [Troubleshooting steps when an Android device is detected but not recognized by Eclipse ADT](http://opensourceforgeeks.blogspot.in/2013/11/troubleshooting-steps-when-eclipse-adt.html).

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem too, the problem was my windows firewall, I just change some Inbound and Outbound setting ( Firewall advance setting ) for abd.exe ( Emulator ) and problem fixed. Do it and reset your emulator.   Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to see my device in the "Devices" window but when I tried to Run the project my device was not shown in the "Pick a device" window. What worked for me was re-plugging my device while I was on the "Pick a device" window and it showed up.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I have the same problem and I solve it thus:

1. Close eclipse
2. Start Windows Task Manager and kill adb process
3. Open eclipse again

Then, go to DDMS perspective and check what devices are connected. Your phone should appears now.